# JavaScript: Extracting webpage contents

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to get extract href table links from a website. Is it possible to do.? If yes the please help me in this regards. I want to use javascript.

i have an external site in which i have a table with some data . Each data is given to a link. i need to extract that link from my page.

Comment: jQuery: `$('#tableId').find('a').map(function() { return this.href; }).get()`

Comment: @Šime Vidas why don't you make that an answer rather than a comment also I don't think its really the OP site  ?

Comment: What is an "href table link"?

Comment: Is "a website" a website you control (and thus can add JS to)? Or is it a third party website?

Comment: Do you want to use client side JavaScript in the browser? Or in a browser extension (like Greasemonkey)? Or are you using something like a standalone V8 engine? Or a server side environment like node.js?

Comment: @mcgrailm I didn't have the time to stick around and enhance the answer (if there would be a need for that).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean by href table links, but if you want to get all href attributes, you can do this:

```
var arr = [],
    as = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    len = as.length;

while( len-- ) {
    arr.push( as[len].getAttribute('href') );
}
```

or if you want them with the domain instead of just the path, you can use the `href` property instead of `getAttribute()`.

```
var arr = [],
    as = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    len = as.length;

while( len-- ) {
    arr.push( as[len].href );
}
```

and to skip when there isn't an `href` attribute, you can add this line to either `while` block.

```
if( as[len].href ) {
    // get the href
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'table links' but you can use jQuery and the [find operator](http://api.jquery.com/find/) `$('body').find('a')` to return all the links within a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't your own website and you want to use Javascript to extract the links then you may want to look at the Greasemonkey extension for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

If you are talking about adding functionlity to your own website for others to use then Greasemonkey isn't the thing you want.